# Room Mailbox Permissions O365 in Outlook

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration

I have migrated my Exchange 2007 on-prem server to o365, using a staged migration.

Everything is syncing great, except for the room calendar in outlook:

I have a room resource named "Leave" it is a calendar whereby all users can add the days they are out of the office. Anyone can do this, I don't need a delegate to approve / etc. In exchange 2007, this was working fine.

I can edit the calendar when using OWA, and all works fine as expected, but not from Outlook (2016) - it keeps giving me permissions issues i.e. "You don't have permissions to create an entry in this folder. etc..".

Right clicking on the room calendar and viewing properties gives the "Cannot display folder properties. The folder may have been deleted or the server... etc".

Any suggestions please? I have tried adding my admin account as a delegate, creating different room calendars.. and still no dice..

Thanks.

Comment: Kind of off topic, but how do you handle when two people take leave at the same time?  Wouldn't that be auto declined as a room conflict?

Comment: Edit: Hmm actually yes msemack - i cant add more than one user to a room mailbox which makes sense (will have to use a shared folder i guess) - but the same problem exists, i cant book a room from outlook, e.g for the "boardroom", only owa / phone apps.. and i cant add to the shared folder calendars either...